# Nestjs/Prisma Rest API - GET [Related field]

Tags: typescript, rest, nestjs, prisma, api-design

I am building my first (non-tutorial) Rest API with Nestjs and Prisma. It is intended to be a simple simulacrum of an inventory management system. It currently has a very simple structure and models items in boxes on shelves. Each of these is represented by a table in a Postgres DB with the following schema and relations (I have only included shelves and boxes for brevity):

```
model Shelf {
  id     String  @id @default(uuid()) 
  boxes  Box[]
}

model Box {
  id     String  @id @default(uuid())
  shelf Shelf @relation(fields:[shelfId], references:[id])
  shelfId String
  items Item[]
}
```

I can create, fetch, filter and delete successfully, but my problem is trying to fetch an array of all the boxes on a specific shelf, and subsequently all items in a specific box.

I have gone through the PrismaClient docs exhaustively and can't seem to find the solution. My thoughts are that it should happen in the shelf controller/service, but I am not certain of this. Currently I have an end point defined in shelves.controller.ts:

```
@Get(':id/boxes') 
@ApiOkResponse({ type: ShelfEntity, isArray: true })
getBoxes(@Param('id') id:string ){
    return this.shelvesService.getBoxes(id)
}
```

with ShelfEntity defined as:

```
export class ShelfEntity implements Shelf {
    @ApiProperty({ required: true })
    id: string
}
```

which queries the prisma client in shelves.service.ts for boxes filtered by the shelfId:

```
getBoxes(id: string) {
    return this.prisma.shelf.findUnique({ where: {id}, select: { boxes:true })
}
```

The expected response from this GET call is an array of Box objects (I base this expectation on https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#select-a-subset-of-fields) but I am getting a 404.  Any help offered would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check for your controller if the actual call lead to the services. 404 should related to NestJs side when it can't access your route.
The prisma select / include worked fine in my case.

Comment: Thank you.  I think you were right but it was swagger not accessing the route. I was using the swagger "Try it out" tool in the browser when I was getting the 404. It seems like this does not actually hit the endpoint because the requested route is localhost:3000/api/shelves/{id}/boxes. Does this seem like an appropriate conclusion? I installed insomnia and ran GET localhost:3000/shelves/{id}/boxes and it worked as expected.

Comment: I think it is base on your global prefix of NestJs setting through setGlobalPrefix() https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/global-prefix#global-prefix . Also if you are behind reverse proxy or something that is modifying the path called, it's worth using addServer of the swagger DocumentBuilder options